# Please help me will the following probability question

Tags: probability, card-games

Consider a game that involves flipping over cards from a standard 52 card deck. What is your probability that  a) at least one of the first two cards is a spade   b) draw a king of diamonds in 5 pick.

Now i know the first answer is 15/34 and the second one is 5/52, but i don't know how to get the answer. Please do me a favor, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Calculate first the chance P that neither of those 2 cards is a spade.

$$P=\frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{38}{51}=\frac{19}{34}$$

The chance that at least one of those 2 cards is a spade is

$$1-P=\frac{15}{34}$$

b) This one you can solve immediately. The chance that the king of diamonds is one of the first 5 cards is $\frac{5}{52}$.